# "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" when parsing JSON

Tags: json, swift

**Note: I would like to know the reason of downvote. I think it's pretty legit question with proper format. I don't really care about votes since I'm only here for learning but whoever is giving the downvote without explanation is discouraging a lot of people to ask and learn.**

I wrote below code for getting json from a webservice, which works fine when I run it in a new "single view project" but it gives `**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**` error when I add it in my project. You can also see where it goes wrong from below screenshot.

[image]

Code:

```
import UIKit

class NewsViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var newsTableView: UITableView!

    var newsTitles : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray() // will contain news contents from API
    var newsURLs : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()     // will contain news URLs from API
    var newsResponse : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray() // will contain server response

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getNews()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    // Calling News Service
    func getNews(){

        var serviceParam: AnyObject = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("key4news")!
        var apiURL = "http://myIP/myWebService?search_text=\(serviceParam)"
        println(apiURL)
        var request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
        request.URL = NSURL(string: apiURL)
        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response:NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in


            var error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSError?> = nil
            let jsonResult: NSDictionary! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: error) as? NSDictionary

            if (jsonResult != nil) {

                self.newsResponse = jsonResult.objectForKey("result") as NSMutableArray

                for var i=0; i<self.newsResponse.count; i++ {
                    self.newsTitles[i] = self.newsResponse[i].objectForKey("title")! as NSString
                    self.newsURLs[i] = self.newsResponse[i].objectForKey("link")! as NSString
                    println("news title: \(self.newsTitles[i])")
                    println("news link: \(self.newsURLs[i])")
                    println("\n\n")
                }

            } else {
                // couldn't load JSON, look at error
                println("jsonResult is nil")
            }
        })
    }

    func tableView(tableView:UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int
    {
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!
    {
        let cell:UITableViewCell=UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "newsItem")
        cell.textLabel?.text = newsTitles[indexPath.row] as NSString

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
        println("you've touched tableviewcell")
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
}
```

And this is my webservice's JSON format (it returns max 10 items in 'result' array):

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "result": [
    {
      "date added": "2014-12-29 00:00:00",
      "link": "http:link3.com",
      "description": "description of first news",
      "title": "title of first news"
    },
    {
      "date added": "2013-10-15 00:00:00",
      "link": "http:link3.com",
      "description": "description of second news",
      "title": "title of second news"
    },
    {
      "date added": "2013-04-09 00:00:00",
      "link": "http:link3.com",
      "description": "description of third news",
      "title": "title of third news"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: with json, you have to sure about the date format. It can be a Dictionary or an Array. In your case, maybe the json content is in Array format but you force to cast to DIctionary? format so it return nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are not getting data from server in response and that's why getting this error.

**You need to do url encoding.**

YOUR CODE

```
var serviceParam: AnyObject = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("key4news")!
var apiURL = "http://myIP/myWebService?search_text=\(serviceParam)"
```

Need to be like

```
var serviceParam: AnyObject = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("key4news")!        
serviceParam = serviceParam.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())!
var apiURL = "http://myIP/myWebService?search_text=\(serviceParam)"
```